# How to use javascript variables in C# code block

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Model.kanal is an array.
I need a loop like this:

```
var boyut = @Model.kanal.Length;
    var knll = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < boyut; i++) {
        knll.push("@Model.kanal[i]"); //this i variable is not defined. Because it is a javascript variable. This is my problem.
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: the short answer: _you can not do this._

Comment: why you run JS loop on Model Array?

Comment: because I need to access the data from the model one by one and write on the screen

Comment: What makes you think that "You cannot do this" Mr.Gelichmann

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the array just like this:

```
var knll = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.kanal));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **JS**

```
var json = `@Json.Serialize(Model.YourArray)`;

var objects = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(objects);
```

Comment: No problem friend :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var boyut = @Model.kanal.Length; // Get Model Array Length

var knll = "@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.kanal))"; // Convert Array into Json and Set a Plan Text

for (var i = 0; i < boyut; i++) {
    knll.push(knll[i]);  // access From 
}
```